# Match words with no hyphen inside

Tags: c++, regex

i need a regex that allow  words which have no hyphen inside them.
For example,  in  a string " non-word   sentence " it should only match "sentence".
I wrote:

```
 "\b(?!\w+[-]\w+)\w+"
```

and it fails:

It  matches not only "sentence" but   also "word".

How to make it ignore  words with hyphens inside?

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? PCRE? Is this for a C++ program, as your tag states?

Comment: To add to @JesseSmith's comment, I'm curious too as to which engine you're using since, AFAIK, no C++ standard library has working regexes (I could be wrong, in which case I'd be happy to be corrected). C++11 core language is pretty much working nowadays but the standard lib is lagging...

Comment: @syam: C++ has regex support as of C++11, e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: @NateKohl: C++11 _specification_ has regex support, but syam is correct that no C++ _implementation_ has working regexes.

Comment: @MooingDuck: LLVM's libc++ (http://libcxx.llvm.org/) currently has reasonable support for <regex>.

Comment: @NateKohl So I stand corrected. ;) (I'll just take your word about this particular implementation, I don't use CLang so I can't test firsthand) But you gotta admit my phrasing was clear, even though I didn't explicitly write the words "implementation" or "specification". ;)

Comment: I can't find anything to verify that.  [This gcc page says "partially complete" and "incomplete" for much of the regex stuff](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011).  AFAIKT, libc++'s regex has quite a ways to go still.

Comment: @MooingDuck LLVM/CLang is a completely different implementation than GCC so it's very possible they got it right (compared to GCC, CLang usually is better on the lib, and quite on par on the core language -- but to be sure of that one needs to use both and since I don't, I have to accept Nate's word ^^)

Comment: @syam: You're totally right; I didn't read your comment very carefully.  :)  My assertion that <regex> in libc++ is "reasonable" comes from it's ability to compile and run most of the examples on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex.  (I wouldn't trust it on production code until the libc++ people make claims that it's ready, however.)

Comment: @Nate Ah well you may still be right too (again, I know nothing about CLang, it may or may not work, I have no idea) but my experience with libstdc++ (GCC) is that regexes compile but don't work as expected. Meh... I guess we'll have to wait a few more weeks/months for them to get it right. Lazy compiler writers... (just kidding, they did an awesome job getting C++11 mostly right so we can't really complain) :)

Comment: @syam: Yup, my experience with libstdc++ is the same; that's why I started trying out libc++.

Comment: Hey, OP! You should check on your questions more often. "I'm just gonna leave this here..." with one (probably bogus) tag makes my heart hurt.

Comment: @MooingDuck libc++ is feature complete (libstdc++ isn’t).

Answer (score 3):

Alright, here's one for PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expression systems, which means most of them):

```
(?<![-])\b[a-zA-Z]+\b(?![-])
```

Let me break it down for you:

`(?<![-])`: Negative look-behind -- "the next thing that matches, look at the thing right before it. If it's a hyphen, ignore this match"

`\b[a-zA-Z]+\b`: A word boundary, a word, a word boundary. Our 'thing'.

`(?![-])`: A negative look-ahead -- "the thing that matched, look at the thing right after it. If it's a hyphen, ignore this match"

[Here it is](http://regexr.com?35hdp) in my favorite online regex tester, RegExr.

Comment: Hey,Jesse, look-behind  + the thing + look-ahead is  really smart.Many thanks!

Comment: Can you Accept the question if it solved your problem? That will help people in the future who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
(?<=[^\s])[a-zA-Z]*(?=[$\s])
```

Comment: @Jesse Smith, I see you are correct, do you know why, I thought that (?<=[^\s]) would force it to match either the beginning of the string or a whitespace, so it should have not matched word.

Comment: [^\s] will match anything not whitespace. So a positive look-behind assertion is saying 'was my current position preceded by anything not whitespace?' which isn't what we are asking. We're asking 'was my current position NOT preceded by a hyphen?'

Comment: And I just noticed your look-ahead: $ means something else in the context of a character class, namely plain old '$'. Were you going for an end-of-string separator? Same with ^ in a character class. Except it's special -- it means negation. [^x] means anything other than the literal letter 'x'. Same for \s. I believe [^\s] is logically equivalent to \S

Comment: Ahh, Thank you for the clarification, that is my bad, I will delete this answer answer since it is quite wrong. Also yes, I was looking for the start/end of the string or whitespaces.

Comment: It's all good: assertions, and regexes in general, are devilishly tricky beasts. At least we all learned something! :)